# SqlLite in Visual Studio 2012 installed by NuGet dosent exist in Data Source for connection

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Premium, and I installed System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64) by NuGet Packages API. I added all available SQLLite References to my WPF x86 Net 4.0 project.

I would like to create an entity model from existing db but there is a problem.
In server explorer I want to add connection but SQLLite does not exist in the Data source.

I tried uninstalling the SQLlite version which I installed manually before, and then reinstalling nuget SQLlite but it still is not working.

I looked over similar topics on Stack Overflow but none helped me out.