# SQLite data source is missing in Visual Studio 2012 Entity Framework Connection

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I have just updated from SQLite 1.0.8x to sqlite 1.0.94.0 to try and use with EF6.

When I try and add a entity data model from an existing database there is no option to select the data source as sqlite as there used to be for the older SQLite. I have installed SQLite from Nuget and from the setup file on the SQLite website for .net4.5/VS2012. I have tried reinstalling and rebooting both VS and my machine and neither worked. I have found many similar problems to this and no answers to this problem. I can add a connection to an SQLite file via server explorer and navigate through the db on the tab in Visual Studio. This now existing connection does not appear when trying to add a new model in EF6, however.

I even found this question on SO that seems to be the same question as mine but has no answers:

[SqlLite in Visual Studio 2012 installed by NuGet dosent exist in Data Source for connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613194/sqllite-in-visual-studio-2012-installed-by-nuget-dosent-exist-in-data-source-for)

It seems strange to me that this issue would exist with no answers/concern about it. Are people shunning the SQLite/EF6 combo? I had EF5 and SQLite running fine.

I know this is technically a duplicate but I do not know what else I can do.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't connect to an SQLite database at all or just that some wizard doesn't display the connection? The first is serious, the second not so much, especially now that people use Code First.

Comment: The wizard does not display SQLite as a possibility when trying to create a DB first model. I don't think I can use Code First for this project.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a fake connection then overwrite the necessary lines in the app.config file or does the wizard do more than setup the app.config file?

Comment: Why add a fake connection? If you add the real connection in app.config doesn't it show in the wizard? Are you talking about the Context generation wizard?

Comment: The sqlite ado.net EF provider is broken with EF6, suggest you report an issue at system.data.sqlite.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this actually solves your issue, but I had the same problem and tried pretty much every solution out there.

Eventually, after installing the correct packages to support VS2012, I also installed [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

After doing so (and a restart of VS) the connection showed up in the Entity Data Model Wizard.

Hope it solves your issue as well.